# Left shift and right shift calculation ..

Tags: binary

i need to calculate left and right shift in java. in java i am able to code this. but i like to know how it calculate . Can any body here enplane me with Example.
 I am using below logic, plz check it's correct or not.

4>>2 ans is 1

**Logic**
4>>2
0100>>2
0001 = 1

Comment: What?${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @cameron Buie I need logic how to calculate sift(left and right)

Comment: @Jani A left shift corresponds by a division by 2. A right shift corresponds to multiplication my 2. This is often handy to keep in mind when doing bit shifting.

Comment: Can any body give logic with Example...

Answer (score 4):

If I correctly understand what you're doing, $$n>>m=\frac{n}{2^m}$$  and $$n<<m=n\cdot 2^m.$$ This is similar to the way that moving a decimal point one place to the left (right) corresponds to division (multiplication) by $10$.

For example, then: $$16>>1=8\\16>>2=4\\16>>3=2,$$ and so on; or the other way, $$5<<1=10\\5<<2=20\\5<<3=40,$$ and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot..It helped me to understand clearly.